# Bourne - Binary operator expected

Tags: unix, sh

Need to check if there is a result of $found_files. However, I got an error "binary operator expected" in the 2nd line of code. Please help.

```
found_files=`find . -name "*.php" -printf '%f '` # find all php files in the current folder
if [ -z $found_files ] ;
then 
    echo "No php file found."
else
    echo -e "$found_files" 
fi
```

Comment: turn on your debugging with `set -x` and you'll see the problem. Good luck.

Comment: You need quotes around `$found_files` when testing with `-z`.